# I need a (preferably free) PDF/Word generator .Net component that can work from a document template

Tags: pdf, ms-word, generator

I'm looking for a .Net component that will allow me to generate Word and/or PDF documents.

This must work on the server without MS Office installation. Preferably free. Also, it needs to be able to generate the documents based on an existing template of some sort i.e. I don't want to generate the whole document from scratch but allow a number of different templates that all have similar content that comes from elsewhere (e.g. database, XML files etc).

My initial investigations have turned up iTextSharp (but not sure if it can work from templates).

Any help that can expedite my investigation time will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use ActivePDF at work with .NET - give it some HTML and it will output a pdf doc. However it isn't free - but we did look at a few other ways and this was 1
http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/
It doesn't do word documents but converts html (your template) to pdf